ASP.NET Page_Load event firing twice
I'm encountering an issue where the Page_Load event in my ASP.NET web page seems to be firing twice, leading to unintended behavior. I have a Page_Load event handler that's supposed to bind data to a GridView only when the page is first loaded (!IsPostBack), but it's executing twice during each page load.
Here's my code :
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Kredas_Franchise_Details
{
    public partial class Franchise_Details : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindGridView();
            }
        }

        private void BindGridView()
        {

            // Connection string
            string connectionString = "*conn_string*;";

            // SQL query to select data from the database
             string query = "SELECT fd.ID, fd.UserName, fd.Name, fd.Email, fd.[AlternateContactNumber], s.Name AS State, c.CityName AS City, fd.Address, fd.LandMark, fd.[PaymentInfo], fd.[RegDate] " +
                "FROM KredasIndia.FranchiseDetails fd " +
                "INNER JOIN KredasIndia.States s ON fd.StateID = s.ID " +
                "INNER JOIN Cities c ON fd.CityID = c.ID";

            // Create connection
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                // Create command 
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                {
                    // Create data adapter
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        // Create DataTable to hold the data
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                        // Fill DataTable with data from the database
                        da.Fill(dt);

                        // Bind DataTable to the GridView
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



It should not be running 2 times. How did you determine load event is running 2 times? You have the if (!IsPostBack), which looks correct. Each button click or post back will of course trigger the page load event each and every time, but the !IsPostBack part will thus not run each time but only on the first real page load. So, page load event always runs first, and one time on page load. For each button click etc., then the page load event runs again, and THEN your code behind stub runs. So, with the !IsPostBack, then your loading of the GV should only run one time and on first page load.

But, i got result table from database two times..
